# Rendering issue on job cards with link to company

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

**Steps to reproduce**

- Add a job position where the company has a linked account
- Mouse over and leave the cursor on the company link

[image]

**Result**

The entirety of the developer-story page is dumped into the job card

- Observed on Chrome 56.0.2924.87
- Reproducible in Firefox 51.0.1

[image]

Comment: Mac OSX - if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks for the report. Reproduced. Taking a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the report. This should now be fixed.

For the curious: this happened because I replaced the use of `this` in some jQuery event handlers with `event.target`. I thought they were equivalent, [but in this case I should have replaced it with `event.currentTarget` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12077859/1114).

Comment: Excellent, seems fine now. Thanks for the update.